# Jquery function fires twice on click and not isolated to one of the tabbed boxes

Tags: jquery, performance, jquery-plugins

jquery function

```
(function ( $ ) {


$.fn.tabbed = function() {

    return this.each(function() { 

    $("a.tab").one('click focus',function (event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        // switch all tabs off
        $(".active").removeClass("active");

        // switch this tab on
        $(this).addClass("active");

        // slide all elements with the class 'content' up
        $(".tab_content").slideUp();

        // Now figure out what the 'title' attribute value is and find the element with that id.  Then slide that down.
        var content_show = $(this).attr("title");
        $("#"+content_show).slideDown();

    });

    });
};

}( jQuery ));
```

Html

```
    <ul class="tabs">
        <li><a href="#" title="content_1" class="tab active">1</a></li>
        <li><a href="#" title="content_2" class="tab">2</a></li>
        <li><a href="#" title="content_3" class="tab">3</a></li>
    </ul>

    <div id="content_1" class="tab_content">
        <p>1</p>
    </div>
    <div id="content_2" class="tab_content">
       <p>2</p>
    </div>
    <div id="content_3" class="tab_content">
       <p>3</p>
    </div>

<div id="tabbed_box_2" class="tabbed_box">
<div class="tabbed_area">


    <ul class="tabs">
        <li><a href="#" title="content_4" class="tab active">4</a></li>
        <li><a href="#" title="content_5" class="tab">5</a></li>
        <li><a href="#" title="content_6" class="tab">6</a></li>
    </ul>

    <div id="content_4" class="tab_content">
        <p>4</p>
    </div>
    <div id="content_5" class="tab_content">
       <p>5</p>
    </div>
    <div id="content_6" class="tab_content">
       <p>6</p>
    </div>

</div>
```

CSS:

```
  #tab_box_1 {
margin: 0 auto;
width: 300px;
}

#tab_box_2 {
margin: 0 auto;
width: 300px;
}
.tab_box h4 {
color: #FFFFFF;
font-family: Arial,Helvetica,sans-serif;
font-size: 23px;
letter-spacing: -1px;
margin-bottom: 10px;
}
.tab_box h4 small {
color: #E3E9EC;
font-family: Verdana,Arial,Helvetica,sans-serif;
font-size: 9px;
font-weight: normal;
left: 6px;
letter-spacing: 0;
position: relative;
text-transform: uppercase;
top: -4px;
}
 .tab_area {
background-color: #red;
border: 1px solid #494E52;
padding: 8px;
}
ul.tabs {
margin: 5px 0 6px;
padding: 0;
}
ul.tabs li {
display: inline;
list-style: none outside none;
}
ul.tabs li a {
background-color: #464C54;
background-image: url("images/tab_off.jpg");
background-position: center bottom;
background-repeat: repeat-x;
border: 1px solid #464C54;
color: #FFEBB5;
font-family: Verdana,Arial,Helvetica,sans-serif;
font-size: 9px;
font-weight: bold;
padding: 8px 14px;
text-decoration: none;
text-transform: uppercase;
}
ul.tabs li a:hover {
background-color: #2F343A;
border-color: #2F343A;
}
ul.tabs li a.active {
 -moz-border-bottom-colors: none;
-moz-border-image: none;
-moz-border-left-colors: none;
-moz-border-right-colors: none;
-moz-border-top-colors: none;
background-color: #FFFFFF;
background-image: url("images/tab_on.jpg");
background-position: center top;
background-repeat: repeat-x;
border-color: #464C54 #464C54 #FFFFFF;
border-style: solid;
border-width: 1px;
color: #282E32;
}
.tab_content {
background-color: #FFFFFF;
background-image: url("images/content_bottom.jpg");
background-position: center bottom;
background-repeat: repeat-x;
border: 1px solid #464C54;
font-family: Arial,Helvetica,sans-serif;
padding: 10px;
}
#content_2, #content_3, #content_5, #content_6 {
display: none;
 }
```

The jquery is firing twice on click and the box is sliding down twice, also when either of the tabbed boxes is clicked it is hiding all the divs on the over tabbed section as well

Anyone come across this before?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When clicking a tab, the "focus" event is also automatically triggered. Simply use "focus" and remove the "click" event.

About your second problem: your explanation is a bit hard to understand, but could it be caused because you're removing all active classes? If you are using the active class on other elements which should not be hidden you should be more specific in your selector, such as:

```
$("a.tab.active").removeClass("active");
```

Comment: yeah the active class is for the selected tab and by default the first tab of each tabbed box. I thought putting it in a function would allow this to just call it on that tabbed_box  only.

Comment: I still have the problem with the active tabs closing on both boxes

Comment: Have you tried being more specific with your .active selector? Try experimenting with $(this).closest('.active') or $(this).parent().find('.active'). You can also try creating a container div around those that you want to close and say $('.containerdiv .active')

Comment: I have tried these but still no lucky here is a link to it http://jsfiddle.net/tmMbM/

Comment: Fixed, it was your selector after all: http://jsfiddle.net/tmMbM/2/ (PS: you can edit posts/comments in case u made a typo)

Comment: Oh yeah sorry im new to using stackoverflow, Thank you so much i've been trying to fix that for weeks haha

Answer (score 0):

**JQUERY BIND**

use this happening this because you are by setting the double click and you putting unbind click and takes and puts a new click

```
$("a.tab").unbind('click focus');
$("a.tab").bind('click focus',function (event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        // switch all tabs off
        $(".active").removeClass("active");

        // switch this tab on
        $(this).addClass("active");

        // slide all elements with the class 'content' up
        $(".tab_content").slideUp();

        // Now figure out what the 'title' attribute value is and find the element with that id.  Then slide that down.
        var content_show = $(this).attr("title");
        $("#"+content_show).slideDown();

    });
```

Comment: Thank you this fixed the double click issue with my functions